# Order Management in Magento2

Tags: magento2, orders, shipping, order-status, packing-slip

I am new to magento and would like to know the best practice of order fulfillment. We receives orders from our ecommerce website to magento and how do I perform the following in magento:

Order picked, packed, shipped, delivered or returned and closed.

Thank you,

Comment: Read this doc http://docs.magento.com/m2/2.0/ce/user_guide/Resources/pdf/Magento_Community_Edition_2.0_User_Guide.pdf